# Angular function is always called twice?

Tags: angular, ngfor

in Angular I iterate over an array with the ngFor directive.
The function **trend** in the HTML Template is called always twice.
**Is there any reason why?**

**HTML-FILE**

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let exercise of exercises">
      Name: {{exercise.name}}<br>      
      Sets: {{exercise.sets}}<span [innerHTML]="trend(exercise.sets,exercise.prev_sets)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
trend(value: any, prev_value: any){
    console.log("Result:" + value);
    return "";
}
```

**CHROME CONSOLE**

```
Result: 12  exercises.component.ts:39 
Result: 12  exercises.component.ts:39
```

Comment: There are 2elements, 1 for each?

Comment: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method/function calls from the template are called on every change detection cycle

To avoid this either bind to a property or create a custom pipe. You can also use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` to reduce the change detection checks

Comment: Thank you all so much. I decided to use a custom pipe and it works great :-)